# Cakephp3 Cookie saves string not array

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to ask about Cakephp3 Cookie component.
Basicly, i have array:

```
$a = ['11','22'];
```

Now, i want to save this array to Cookie:

```
$this->Cookie->write('Ids',$a);
```

Now when i debug this cookie Ids, it returns srting, not array:

```
var_dump = string(9) "{["11","22"]}"
```

My question is, how can i write this values as array in cookie in Cakephp3.

Thank You.
I have tried to explode this strong, but a would like to do it in elegant way.

Comment: How are you reading the cookie?

Comment: $this->Cookie->read('Ids'),but this show nothing.
In debugkit, cookie looks like:
Ids["114","120"]




But i have got another cookie:
State{"z":"US","zip":"665} - and this works fine.